# С#. Как синхронизировать две группы потоков, каждая из которых должна ждать окончание выполнения другой

Tags: c#, .net, многопоточность

Есть условно две группы потоков:

1. Группа потоков, не осуществляющих доспуп в общую память с возможностью работать в многопоточном режиме.
2. Группа потоков, осуществляющих доспуп в общую память, которая нуждается в синхронизации (выполняются строго по одному).
   Специфика тут такая, что если возникает хотя бы один поток из группы 2, он должен подождать окончание всех потоков группы 1 (если такие есть), и только после этого стартовать. Также и в обратную сторону. Если возникает поток из группы 1, прежде чем стартовать, он должен подождать завершения всех потоков группы 2.

То-есть, две группы потоков не могут выполнятся одновременно.
Для определения в какую группу попадает какой поток, у каждого из них есть булевый идентификатор.
Важно, что 1-ая группа потоков, если она стартовала, должна всегда выполнятся в многопоточном режиме! А 2-ая - всегда в однопоточном.

Проблема в том, что Parallel.For, создающий эти группы, сам может быть вызван из разных потоков, поэтому невозможно выполнить разделение на две группы до выполнения Parallel.For, чтобы выполныть их последовтельно.

Насколько я вижу, ни один из объектов синхронизации не позворляет просто подождать окончание выполнения потока, без последующего лока этого объекта тем потоком, который ждал. Можно конечно в цикле проверять Monitor.IsEntered (locker), и потом ждать, но это не рекомендуется в самом мануале к Monitor.

Comment: В вашем описании не понятно следующее: если потоки из группы 1 не осуществляют доступ к разделяемому ресурсу и могут работать многопоточно, то почему они вынуждены ждать завершение всех потоков из группы 2?

Comment: Судя по всему, я неправильно варазился. Группа 1 только читает из этой области памяти, а группа 2 - и читает и пишет в нее. Еще одно уточнение. Если группа 2 сформировалась, то она должна полностью закончить выполнение (все функции) прежде чем группа 1 начнет чтение из общей памяти, иначе данные в памяти будут не валидними.

Comment: Может проще обойтись какой-то потокобезопасной коллекцией вместо попыток регуляции потоков между собой?

Comment: На первый взгляд это типичный [ReaderWriterLock](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.readerwriterlockslim?view=netcore-3.1)

Comment: Не совсем понял, что такое "вторая группа потоков должна выполняться в однопоточном режиме". У потоков нет иерархии, нельзя несколько потоков засунуть в один родительский поток. Очевидно, путаница с терминологией в вопросе. Может имелось с виду "вторая группа задач должна работать в однопоточном режиме"?

Comment: Вы правы. Имеятся введу задачи выполняемые в однопоточном редиме. Я так, не совсем корректно, выразился потому, что Parallel.For изначально создает несколько потоков по одному на каждую задачу, а потом для 2-ой группы я вынужден их по одному выполнять.

Comment: Спасибо за ответы. Но я попробую еще немного разьяснить. Часть задачи - функций, которые выполняются в Parallel.For находятся в сторонней библиотеке. Внутри этой библиотеки есть статический синглтон к которому эти функции могут обращаться. Будут ли они обращатся или нет определяю я, при помощи передачи булевого параметра, при вызове этой функция в определенном потоке. К сожалению я не контролирую когда внутри dll идет обрашение к общей области памяти, а сама dll не имеет внутренних механизмов синхронизации. Поэтому обернуть вызовы при помощи ReaderWriterLock не получиться.